# Is there a "vote history" that shows every single up- and downvote including the revokes of votes?

Tags: discussion, votes

Is there a "vote history" that shows every single up- and downvote including the revokes of votes? Does it get recorded in the database at all? There is the time line for a post and my reputation changes history but those doesn't give me all the details.

It would also interested me how the votes develop over several edits. But this would be a second question, not sure if I should post both into one question-post.

Comment: Do you have an example of such a question?

Comment: @DavidPostill I noticed changes in my reputation due to downvote and upvote. When I wanted to look it up it was gone. I thing in was on the [Restart-Question](https://superuser.com/questions/1283297/is-it-possible-to-quickly-restart-firefox-quantum), but I'm not sure anymore.

Comment: The question timeline (https://superuser.com/posts/1283297/timeline) will show votes, but only a daily summary.

Comment: There is no way to tell if votes (downvote followed by a later upvote) are cast by the same person (as votes are anonymous). Having said that, community managers or devs might have access to this information, but mods and other mere mortals don't.

Comment: @DavidPostill ok, I'm wondering... if you (or anyone else) have time, could you please up- or downvote two of my questions or answers and reverse one of the votes on the same day and the next one on the next day?

Comment: @Albin No. We should not vote on your questions/answers because you ask us to. In addition votes can only be reversed if the question or answer is edited in between the 2 votes.

Comment: @DavidPostill ok, didn't know that. So what happend in my case? I saw my reputation go down 2 points because of a downvote when I wanted to look it up, there was no entry in my reputation history.

Comment: @DavidPostill to answer my own question, I thing there was a down vote put on the post and this down vote was revoked again. I just tried it myself, it works. Is there a time slot in which I can revoke my vote and after which it gets locked so I can not revoke it any more until an edit is made?

Comment: @albin 5 minutes. See [Why can't I change my vote if the post has been edited during the initial 5mn grace period?](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/38759)

Comment: @DavidPostill thanks (i rephrased my question according to my "new knowledge")